# Schrodinger matter-field equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, variational-calculus

> Given the Lagrangian Density: $$L=i \hbar \dot{\psi} \psi^* -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla\psi^* \nabla\psi-V\psi\psi^*$$ and the Lagrange equation: $$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}-\nabla\cdot \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \nabla\psi}-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\psi}}=0$$
>
> a)  Obtain the equation:
>   $$i\hbar\dfrac{\partial \psi^*(\vec{r}, t)}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\psi^*(\vec{r}, t)+V(\vec{r}, t)\psi^*(\vec{r}, t)=0$$
>
> b) Taking $L´=L^*$ and the conjugate of (2) obtain the Schrodinger matter-field equation
>   $$-i\hbar\dfrac{\partial \psi(\vec{r}, t)}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi(\vec{r}, t)+V(\vec{r}, t)\psi(\vec{r}, t)=0$$

I´ve started with the second equation, which is supposed to lead to the conjugate if the field equation (4), which is equivalent to the desired equation.
The text suggest to make a direct variation with respect to $\psi^*$, but our professor suggested to take $L´=L^*$.

So, i calculated

$$L´=-\hbar\dot{\psi}\psi--\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla\psi^* \nabla\psi$$

But i can´t see how to connect it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calculating the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian $L$ with respect to $\dot{\psi}, \nabla\psi$ and $\psi$ ? This would be the first thing I suggest.

After that, try calculating $$\frac{\partial\,}{\partial t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot\psi}\,\quad\quad\mbox{and}\quad\quad \nabla\cdot\frac{\partial L}{\partial \nabla\psi}\,.$$

Also, try determining the complex conjugate of $L$ and the formal expression for the complex conjugate of

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi} - \nabla\cdot\frac{\partial L}{\partial\nabla\psi} - \frac{\partial\,}{\partial t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\psi}=0\,.
$$

After you've done that see what you get and calculate the result explicitly.

p.s. $L$ is technically a Lagrangian and not a Lagrangian density.